# Azure Functions : C# compile error with System.Linq.Expressions

Tags: azure, azure-functions, linq-expressions

I have an Azure function that is responsible for connecting to an Azure AD and retrieving some Azure AD information.

When I use the `.Expand()` property on the `.Users` , I receive the following compilation error:

```
   activeDirectoryClient.Users.Expand(x => x.MemberOf).ExecuteAsync().Result;

    (38,17): error CS0012: The type 'Expression<>' is defined in an assembly that is not referenced. You must add a reference to assembly 'System.Linq.Expressions
```

I have added the namespace correctly, and also tried to add it in the project.json :

```
{
"frameworks": {
"net46":{
  "dependencies": {
    "Microsoft.IdentityModel.Clients.ActiveDirectory": "3.13.5",
    "Microsoft.Azure.ActiveDirectory.GraphClient": "2.1.0",
    "System.Linq": "4.0.0",
    "System.Linq.Expressions": "4.0.0"
   }
  }
 }
}
```

Are there known issues with `Linq.Expressions` in Azure Functions solution using C#?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are no issues with Linq.Expressions in Azure Functions.

Working example of HttpTriggerCSSharp using Linq.Expression:

project.json

```
{
"frameworks": {
"net46":{
  "dependencies": {
    "Microsoft.IdentityModel.Clients.ActiveDirectory": "3.13.5",
    "Microsoft.Azure.ActiveDirectory.GraphClient": "2.1.0"
   }
  }
 }
}
```

run.csx

```
#r "System.Linq.Expressions"

using System.Net;
using Microsoft.Azure.ActiveDirectory.GraphClient;
using Microsoft.IdentityModel.Clients.ActiveDirectory;

public static async Task<HttpResponseMessage> Run(HttpRequestMessage req, TraceWriter log)
{
    log.Info("C# HTTP trigger function processed a request.");

    ActiveDirectoryClient activeDirectoryClient = new ActiveDirectoryClient(new Uri("https://graph.windows.net/" + "testdomain"),
                                                                                async () => await AcquireTokenAsyncForApplication());
    IUser user = activeDirectoryClient.Users.Where(u => u.UserPrincipalName == "admin@testdomain.onmicrosoft.com").ExecuteSingleAsync().Result;

    return req.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK, "Hello");

}

public static async Task<string> AcquireTokenAsyncForApplication()
{
    return "test";
}
```

Comment: Hi Alexey,
Thank you for the fast response.  I have the same using clauses and the same project.son entries.  
    var activeDirectoryClient = new ActiveDirectoryClient(new Uri("https://graph.windows.net/" + aadTenantName),                                                async () => { return await GetAccessToken(aadTenantName, clientID, clientSecret); });
    var users = activeDirectoryClient.Users.Expand(x => x.MemberOf).ExecuteAsync().Result; //This gives me a compilation error
    //var users = activeDirectoryClient.Users.ExecuteAsync().Result; This compiles correctly.

Comment: Hi Jens. I edited my answer. Try to remove "System.Linq.*" dependencies from project.json and add #r "System.Linq.Expressions" in run.csx. This code compiles without errors for me.

Comment: Hi Alexey. Indeed, this works correctly. Thanks for helping me out with that.

I do, however, not understand what was wrong with my initial thinking :-)

Comment: #r is used for external asseblies
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-reference-csharp#referencing-external-assemblies

package.json is used for nuget packages
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-reference-csharp#package-management